# XMPP - iOS One of End do not Get Message sometimes

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, openfire

I am using Openfire Server for XMPP. Generally it is working very nice and perfectly but in some case One of two end is not getting Message from Other End.

Lets say Two USers A and B in my case:

- User A sent Message to B, but B do not Received any message
- I checked on Openfire server in such case I found the User B
  disconnected.*(that Means User B might be disconnected)*
- Then UserB sent Message to A. So here i have checked the presence
  of A before sending the Message and I found that A was Unavailable
  for B,    but A was showing Online In OpenfireConsole. Eventouh the Message was Received by User A *(that means User B was succeed in sending Message to Openfire)*
- I Killed the App from    IPhone and Opened it again  I got All the
  Messages sent from the    User A.

What should I do to avoid such a weird Case in future.

Comment: I am facing same issue with my setup. Did you found any solution?